# Converting a high resolution png format logo to tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, png

I have a logo in png format (black and white) for my University that needs to be used in different colours. For a set of forms that a couple of students are developing, it is essential to change logo colour depending on the form that it is being used in.

The logo is really complex (very few straight lines).

I have searched but there does not seem to be a way to use \includegraphics to change image color. So, the possible solution that I have hit upon involves converting the logo to tikz code and then using the full power of xcolor package should become possible. That leads to a second question - how do I convert a png image to tikz code?

I have been using geogebra to generate tikz code from stuff I draw, but I do not think (haven't tried) if that will work for an image imported into geogebra.

Comment: Take a look at [colorize external images using pdflatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117336/colorize-external-pictures-using-pdflatex). Maybe that approach is easier than converting the image to a vector format.

Comment: inkscape2tikz does not work (seems like I need to convert png to svg before I can use it) - just outputs an empty tikzpicture. This colorize option is interesting. Is there anything that can replace all black color in an image with some other color?